# How to redirect from a post request Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 5.1.5

I am trying to redirect to the request page upon post request:
I have an Ajax request from the frontend

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<%= admin_one_time_link_clicks_expire_post_path(@one_time_link_clicks.first.one_time_link.id) %>",
      data: {otl_clicks: all},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: ()=>{
        console.log("asdasd")
      }
    })
```

This is the route:

```
post 'one_time_links/:id/expire_click' => 'one_time_links#expire'
```

And the controller method:

```
  def expire
    puts "=============================="
    puts "Request Method: #{request.method}"
    puts "Request data: #{params}"
    puts "=============================="
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end
```

I can see the request parameters in the controller action, hence the route and the request is right. But I cant redirect back to the page of the request.

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_to ...` only works for http requests, not for ajax. If you want' to redirect on the ajax responde then you have to change the current location on your success callback `window.location = "some_url"`. But actually, I'm not sure where you expect to "go back", since you are already on the referrer page, you don't have to redirect to it, maybe you just want to `window.location.reload()`.

Comment: Makes sense. 

What is the difference between HTTP and Ajax request? I mean they are both HTTP, aren't they? 

You are right `reload` is more appropriate in my case.
But still I think in order to make the response semantically correct I suppose I have to change response status code to 3xx I think. Is that correct?

In general what is the correct way to do this "reload"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, when I said a "http requests" I meant a traditional synchronous HTTP request, AJAX is a technology that uses async http requests. You can handle different HTTP statuses with the `statusCode` option when you do a jquery's ajax request https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. I don't think there's a "correct" way, you can reload the page, go to another page, update the parts of the UI that need to change instead of reloading the page (harder but more user friendly). Modern JS frameworks uses JSON responses and only updates the parts that changed, but it depends.